# Removed a notification extension in Xcode and now app won't build

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

In a seemingly never ending bid to get local notifications and push notifications to work on the same app, I tried managing the push notifications with a notifications service in Xcode, which didn't help... Now the problem.

... I removed the extension and clicked 'remove references to the extension' and now the project won't build! It fails with

```
  error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/nick/AndroidStudioProjects/myApp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner':
1) Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/nick/AndroidStudioProjects/myApp/ios/Runner/Runner' to '/Users/nick/AndroidStudioProjects/myAPP/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner'
2) Target 'Runner' has link command with output '/Users/nick/AndroidStudioProjects/myApp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner'
```

This is due to a copy command and a link command both pointing to

```
'/Users/nick/AndroidStudioProjects/myApp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner'
```

I know there are a few bugs reported for flutter with this duplicate file error, but I don't think this is my problem since it only arrived when I deleted the notification service.  Also most of the fixes don't work (switching between new and legacy doesn't fix it) or aren't relevant (there is nothing in my  build phases 'embedded frameworks' section).

Answer (score 0):

Ok - found the answer.  Adding the extension seemed to also add Runner to the 'Copy Bundle Resources' in 'Build Phases section of Xcode. Seems innocuous enough but it shouldn't be there (at least not if there is no notification extension).  I removed it and am back up and running.